# How can I generate DOM element dynamically with attribute / event binding in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a component which is dependent on a configuration json file. It's content is dynamic so I need to add the elements dynamically.

I have the following lines in my controller for example:

```
const item: HTMLElement = this.renderer.createElement('div');
this.renderer.addClass(item, 'item');
```

This will generate a simple div:

```
<div class="item"></div>
```

How can I generate it with attribute / event binding, so it could be something like this:

```
<div class="item" [style]="property1" (click)="functionName()"></div>
```

Edit:

To be more specific, I'd like to generate this structure:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="toggler" (click)="onTogglerClick(3)">accessories</div>
    <navbar-svg-caret></navbar-svg-caret>

    <div class="menu" [style]="visibility[3]">
        <div class="item">face masks</div>
        <div class="item">beanies</div>
        <div class="item">embroidered beanies</div>
        <div class="item">bucket hats</div>
        <div class="item">caps</div>
        <div class="item">neck sleeves</div>
        <div class="item">socks</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it always a div with class, style and a click function?

Comment: That was just an example. Usually it's a div with a click event for a dropdown toggle and a div with style for it's corresponding dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about ****ngFor*** with JSON object.

It's bit tricky to bind the events for dynamically created DIV.

```
<span *ngFor="let object of yourObject">
     <div class="{{object.class}}" [style]="object.property1" (click)="functionName(object)"> {{object.lable}} </div>
</span>
```

Happy Coding.. :)